# Why does this website print blank in Chrome for Windows? It's flawless on my Mac. (@media print)

Tags: jquery, html, css, dom, media-queries

So I am currently working on a web application that shows a list clients with a list of transactions underneath it. Users need to have the ability to print an individual client's transaction log or all transactions.

I am using tables to display the data. In the @media print CSS, I have the following:

```
table{
  display:none; 
}
table.show-data-block{
  display:table; 
}
```

Initially, all tables have the class .show-data-block. However, I bind print buttons (located next to the client name) with the following:

```
$('.print-log').click(function(e){
        $('.show-data-block').removeClass('show-data-block');
        //I know, lots of nesting           
        var clientTable=$(this).parent().parent().parent().parent();
        if(!$('.'+$(clientTable).data('owns')).length<=0){
            $(clientTable).addClass("show-data-block"); 
        }
        $('.'+$(clientTable).data('owns')).addClass("show-data-block");
        window.print();
        //just to be safe
        setTimeout(function(){
            $('table').addClass('show-data-block');
        },500);
    });
```

On Chrome for Windows, this is the result:
[Frustrating Printing Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rSkpL.png)
\

HOWEVER, for some reason, when someone clicks the button a second time, it shows up correctly. On my Mac (Chrome), it shows up correctly the first time.

Our contracts with clients give us the luxury of only having to develop for Chrome so this only needs to work on Chrome.

Does anyone know how to fix this? I have been trying to figure it out for so long and users/clients don't realize that optimizing for printing on the web is one of the most frustrating things you could ever give to a web developer. :(

Comment: The fact that the second time, you want to print out the results, it works... Does mean the script works. The problem you have here (I think) is simply that your script isn't finished by the time you print. I myself am not that of an expert so I can't suck out a solution out of my thumb this moment :)

Comment: Unfortunately, I have tried adding a setTimeout for window.print() but it still doesn't work :/

Comment: Are the lines in that screen shot something you render in the list or just a page background? Did you try Chrome's inspector to debug it (Inspector > hamburger > Show Console > Rendering tab > Emulate Media : print)? Do you use custom typefaces for printing? Do you reset the size/color of the text?

Comment: @aardian I'm using bootstrap and those lines are the border-bottoms of the tr's. I did try to debug it and it's fine on Windows and Mac. Doesn't show up the same way when printing. I don't use any custom typefaces and the text is always black. There is never a state where the text is white.

Answer (score 0):

So I ended up solving this issue. @aardian was right; part of the issue was the fact that I was using a custom typeface. I realized the template I used sets the font to "Open Sans." Adding this solved the issue:

```
table tr > *{
    font-family:"Helvetica",sans-serif !important;
    /*This ensures the font renders properly.*/
    color:#000 !important 
    /*There are no styles setting the font to white but for some reason, this was needed.*/
}
```